# getting data async from Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I am trying to fetch some data from a firebase collection, however I cannot seem to get it to work properly.

My code is as follows:-

component:-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPlayers } from '../../redux/players/players.actions';

class Players extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchPlayers(); 
    }

    render() {
        const { players } = this.props;

        // const playerItems = players.map(player => (
        //     <div key={player.id}>
        //         <h3>{player.name}</h3>
        //     </div>
        // ));

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>PLAYERS</h1>
                {/* {playerItems} */}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    players: state.players.items,
    newPlayer: state.players.item
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchPlayers})(Players);
```

My actions file looks like this :-

```
import { FETCH_PLAYERS, NEW_PLAYER } from "./players.types";
import { getPlayers, addPlayer } from '../../db/firebase/players.firebase';

// this syntax below will return the dispatch (to the reducer)
export const fetchPlayers = () => dispatch => {
  const players = getPlayers();
  dispatch({
    type: FETCH_PLAYERS,
    payload: players
  });
};

export const createPlayer = playerToAdd => dispatch => {
    addPlayer(playerToAdd);
    dispatch({
        type: NEW_PLAYER,
        payload: playerToAdd
  });
};
```

And my db function is as follows :-

```
import firebase from "../../config/firebase";

const db = firebase.firestore();

export const getPlayers = () => {
    const players = fetchData();
    return players;
}

export const addPlayer = (playerToAdd) => {
    db.collection("players").add({ ...playerToAdd });
}

const fetchData = async () => {
    let playerArr = [];
    await db.collection("players")
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            playerArr = playerArr.concat(doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });

    return playerArr;

}
```

My problem is that in my component, the players remains as a promise, and the fetchData() db call is being returned after.

How can I await the array to be populate first (in the fetchData()) and then pass this to my component through the actions?

Thanks for your help, very much appreciated!

Comment: this does not work

Comment: I tried this :- const players = fetchData().then(players => return players); but i am getting an error on the return

Comment: players.then(players => return players); is throwing an error '{' expected

Comment: I tried this :-    const players = fetchData().then(players => {return players});
still returning a promise

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix it in this way, not sure if this is the correct way though, still fairly new to Redux:-

component:-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPlayers } from '../../redux/players/players.actions';

class Players extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchPlayers(); 
    }

    render() {

        const {players} = this.props;
        let playerItems = ''

        if (players) {
            playerItems = players.map(player => (
                <div key={player.id}>
                    <h3>{player.name}</h3>
                </div>
            ));
        }


        return (
            <div>
                <h1>PLAYERS</h1>
                    {playerItems}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    players: state.players.items,
    newPlayer: state.players.item
});
```

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchPlayers})(Players);

actions:-

```
import { FETCH_PLAYERS, NEW_PLAYER } from "./players.types";
import { getPlayers, addPlayer } from '../../db/firebase/players.firebase';

// this syntax below will return the dispatch (to the reducer)
export const fetchPlayers = () => async dispatch => {
  const players = await getPlayers();
  dispatch({
    type: FETCH_PLAYERS,
    payload: players
  });
};

export const createPlayer = playerToAdd => dispatch => {
    addPlayer(playerToAdd);
    dispatch({
        type: NEW_PLAYER,
        payload: playerToAdd
  });
};
```

firebase:-

```
import firebase from "../../config/firebase";

const db = firebase.firestore();

export const getPlayers = async () => {
    const players = await fetchData();
    return players;
}

export const addPlayer = (playerToAdd) => {
    db.collection("players").add({ ...playerToAdd });
}

const fetchData = async () => {
    let playerArr = [];
    await db.collection("players")
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            playerArr = playerArr.concat(doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });

    return playerArr;

}
```

In this way its working however if you have any suggestions, more than welcome to listen to.

Thanks